# How to replace standard testng with reportNG features

Tags: java, selenium, testng, autotest, reportng

This is my pom.xml, it has 2 reportNG reporters mentioned twice in the pom.xml file.

I added both because i read 2 different instructions, i suspect i need to exclude one - either  part or  that contains reportNG stuff.

I don't know which one to exclude,but right now my test suite runs and produces standard testNG output - no fancy reportNG is working! how do I make custom reportNG html page?

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>testing.naimikz</groupId>
    <artifactId>erjan_test_naimikz_selenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>erjan's example selenium program</name>
    <listeners>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
  </listeners>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.2</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.8</source>
                     <target>1.8</target>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also,should i use some logger or just println statements in every test case?
I want my report to have log statements, screenshots of failed tests available - all in one page like this:
[image: kk]

Answer (score 0):

did you turn off default listeners in your project?
[image]

Comment: yes i did it, still does not work, only testNG giving reports